# Why does SQLite say it can't read SQL from a file?

Tags: sqlite

I have a bunch of SQL in a file, which creates the tables and so forth.  The problem is that the .read command simply returns "can't open xxx" when I try to execute it.  I've set the permissions to everybody read/write, but that didn't help.  I can cat the file from the command line and see it fine.

This is under Mac OS 10.6.3.

Anybody have any idea here?  Thanks!

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/download

Comment: Can you post a transcript from the command line?  First change to the directory and do `ls -l` to show the .sql file in a directory with its permissions.  Then execute `sqlite`.  Then execute `.read file`  The only time I've ever seen "can't open xxx" is when I specify the wrong path or I have no permission, so I'm not sure off hand.  Try quoting the filename in the .read command.  Try a simpler filename if you have non-ASCII characters in it maybe.  You can edit this post to add the info once you have it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the source code in [shell.c](http://www.sqlite.org/src/artifact?name=46a1757c152bba687f647b571693bfa223d3354d), where the sqlite3 utility executes the `.read` and tries to read the .sql file:

```
  if( c=='r' && strncmp(azArg[0], "read", n)==0 && nArg==2 ){
    FILE *alt = fopen(azArg[1], "rb");
    if( alt==0 ){
      fprintf(stderr,"can't open \"%s\"\n", azArg[1]);
    }else{
      process_input(p, alt);
      fclose(alt);
    }
  }else
```

You can see that the utility will print "can't open xxx" only when the call to [fopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) fails.  Pity they don't print errno for you, but this info should really help you narrow down the problem as not specific to sqlite.

You're either specifying the path wrong (try quoting it), you don't have permission, or the file really doesn't exist (meaning that there's something different in how you're using `cat` and `.read`, like the current directory is different).

Answer (score 2):

Watch out for the ; at the end. .read does not like ;'s.